# Activity failed on start

Tags: android

My project is not jet debugged. Possibly, it has bugs, but I can not debug it while activity not starts. Please, help me to start debugging. Zipped Eclipse project you can find at 
http://f-bit.ru/249104

Message of AVD is as following:

"The application blucar (process medynets.dmytro) has stopped unexpectedly. Please try again."

LogCat:

```
10-07 21:14:20.584: E/AndroidRuntime(280): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
10-07 21:14:20.584: E/AndroidRuntime(280): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to        instantiate     activity ComponentInfo{medynets.dmytro/medynets.dmytro.BluCar}:        java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: medynets.dmytro.BluCar in loader   dalvik.system.PathClassLoader      [.]
10-07 21:14:20.584: E/AndroidRuntime(280):  at           android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2585)
10-07 21:14:20.584: E/AndroidRuntime(280):  at       android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2679)
10-07 21:14:20.584: E/AndroidRuntime(280):  at android.app.ActivityThread.access      $2300(ActivityThread.java:125)
10-07 21:14:20.584: E/AndroidRuntime(280):  at android.app.ActivityThread $H.handleMessage  (ActivityThread.java:2033)
10-07 21:14:20.584: E/AndroidRuntime(280):  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage (Handler.java:99)
10-07 21:14:20.584: E/AndroidRuntime(280):  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
10-07 21:14:20.584: E/AndroidRuntime(280):  at android.app.ActivityThread.main (ActivityThread.java:4627)
10-07 21:14:20.584: E/AndroidRuntime(280):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative (Native Method)
10-07 21:14:20.584: E/AndroidRuntime(280):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke (Method.java:521)
10-07 21:14:20.584: E/AndroidRuntime(280):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit $MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:868)
10-07 21:14:20.584: E/AndroidRuntime(280):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main (ZygoteInit.java:626)
10-07 21:14:20.584: E/AndroidRuntime(280):  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native  Method)
10-07 21:14:20.584: E/AndroidRuntime(280): Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException:  medynets.dmytro.BluCar in loader dalvik.system.PathClassLoader[.]
10-07 21:14:20.584: E/AndroidRuntime(280):  at dalvik.system.PathClassLoader.findClass (PathClassLoader.java:243)
10-07 21:14:20.584: E/AndroidRuntime(280):  at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass (ClassLoader.java:573)
10-07 21:14:20.584: E/AndroidRuntime(280):  at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass (ClassLoader.java:532)
10-07 21:14:20.584: E/AndroidRuntime(280):  at android.app.Instrumentation.newActivity (Instrumentation.java:1021)
10-07 21:14:20.584: E/AndroidRuntime(280):  at  android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2577)
10-07 21:14:20.584: E/AndroidRuntime(280):  ... 11 more
```

Comment: Can you post the AndroidManifest?

Comment: Try to start with a clean state and comment out the code in the activity, and then gradually uncomment it. If the problem is not in the AndroidManifest.xml this should help to understand problem.

Comment: Can you post your code?

Comment: `Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException:  medynets.dmytro.BluCar`

Answer (score 1):

It's because you've set an Activity into the Manifest which actually doesnt exist. Please try to pay attention to the names of the activity and package names. Probably you've some typo error.

Edit:

OKAY I found the error:

Delete this from your manifest:

```
android:allowBackup="true"
android:allowTaskReparenting="true"
android:enabled="true"
android:hasCode="false
android:testOnly="false"
```

And then, app will still crash, but because you didn't add permissions about WAKE_LOCK.

```
 <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK" />
```

Then app runs correctly!

Comment: Thank you for your attention. I have edited res/values/strings/app_name to BluCar (instead of blucar), saved strings file, refreshed project and run on AVD. Sorry, there was no positive result. Have you any idea?

Comment: Check this on manifest: android:name="medynets.dmytro.blucar". If you've an entry like this on an Activity, it means you've a class named "blucar" inside package medynets.dymtro

Comment: Yes, you are right! Now I can debug my application. Thank you very much for help! It is pity that I have no right of vote :(

Answer (score 0):

Are you using libs? This error usually occurs when the libraries are under /lib and not under /libs.

Comment: Thank you for your attention. Sorry, I use no external libraries. My folder includes only generated libraries. You can see details of my project here: f-bit.ru/249104 . Just click the button "Скачать".

Answer (score 0):

Your logcat says

**java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: medynets.dmytro.BluCar in loader**

Seems like you've added libraries but not imported correctly..

Please try adding libraries

Properties (on right of project) -> Java Build Path -> in Libraries Tab -> Add external JARS -> Choose you jar file..

Hope this helps....

Comment: Thank you for your attention. Sorry, I use no external libraries. My folder includes only generated libraries. You can see details of my project here: http://f-bit.ru/249104 . Just click the button "Скачать".